# Deterministic thread cancelation

Tags: scheduling, thread

Is there a way to deterministicly cancel threads (Light-weight process) in linux. Let say I want to cancel a thread because it is possible in an infinite loop or my scheduler requires it. How would one do that?

Comment: What are you using the threads for? I would imagine that any badly written threading code (that uses locks), can easily get into dead lock, if you were to kill it. Or if you killed it and freed its lock, would cause corruption. Therefore asking it nicely would be the only way, in this case. However if there are no (locks / no shared writable data), then you could kill it.

Comment: Good point, on shared data and yes there is and will be shared data, and there should be a possibility to kill the thread. Now my problem is that I have to do it gracefully, in an ordered manner. This is on it self a contradiction but that is another story. The worst part is that Linux threads have this mechanism disabled (sometimes) and there will probably be a memory leak. But regardless I still have to know if this can be done.